# How to assign a specific ViewController to a UIView (in UICollectionView)?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiview, uicollectionview

I searched the web for hours but I can't find a solution to my problem.

I have a **View** in my storyboard that contains a **UICollectionView**. I've set the cells of the UICollectionView to be really big (only one can appear on the screen, you have to swipe horizontally to see the others). In my application, I use this layout to ask the user some questions, one after another. The user can respond to those questions by touching buttons, move around a map, select a date, etc... Each questions have the same layout; they are displayed in a box, with a title label and a button. That's why I chose to use a UICollection View.

**I want to display a specific view (the options that allows the user to answer (buttons, Map, DatePicker, etc..)) for each questions in the blue rectangle (see picture below).**

[A screenshot of my view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z1pFi.jpg)

My idea was to create multiple ViewControllers in my StoryBoard and be able to tell : "ok, for the first question (first cell), put the view XXX in the container, for the second, put the view YYY, etc...".

**How can I do this ?**

*I've tried to add a ContainerView but we can only link one view in the storyboard.*

I want to able to do something like this :

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SearchQuestionBox
    cell.questionAnswersZone.view = storyboard.viewNumberOne  //Just for the idea haha

    return cell

}
```

Comment: You can create custom collection cell for each question if you want to show them in the collection view.

Comment: Why not but I will have to place the title and the button on each custom collection cell and if I decide to change something, i will have to change it on each one, which is not really clean... No ?

Comment: Then create custom view, load it from xib and add as subview to the custom cell. Custom cell will have title and button, and view which will behave as container for your custom view

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest not using multiple view controllers.

Instead you could just add the views for each cell to the one main view controller. Keep in mind you can set a views frame to be offscreen.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! Don't you thing that there existe a better way for doing that ? Because I will have to copy/paste the label and the button on each frames. And if one day, the design changes, I will have to apply the new design on each single frame, which is not really clean no ? I don't know if I have understood correctly